# Tkinter Entry Field Capture AttributeError:

Tags: python, tkinter, xlsxwriter, tkinter-entry

I want to capture the data in the entry field from the second window defined under output. When I click submit get the following message: AttributeError: 'NoneType object has no attribute 'get'.

I feel like this should be an easy fix and do not understand why can't I capture the data from the entry field?

```
from tkinter import *
import xlsxwriter

class MyFirstGUI:
    def __init__ (self, master):
        master.title("Main")
        master.geometry("400x400+230+160")

        button1 = Button(master, text="1", command= self.output).grid(row=0, column=0)


    def output(self):

        cw1= Toplevel(root)
        cw1.title("cw1")
        cw1.geometry("400x300+160+160")

        self.b2 = Button(cw1, text="Submit",command = self.write_to_xlsx).grid(row=0, column=2) 
        self.l2 = Label(cw1, text="New Specimen").grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.e2 = Entry(cw1).grid(row=0, column=1)


    def write_to_xlsx(self):

        workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('tkintertest19.xlsx')
        worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
        worksheet.write_string('C1', self.e2.get())
        workbook.close() 


root = Tk()
my_gui = MyFirstGUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is split the line

```
self.l2 = Label(cw1, text="New Specimen").grid(row=0, column=0)
```

into

```
self.l2 = Label(cw1, text = "New Specimen")
self.l2.grid(row=0, column=0)
```

Non-intuitive as this may seem, the `grid`/`pack`/`place` functions return `None`, so the whole shebang (`Label().grid()`) returns `None`. The solution is simply to split it up so that you get the right thing when you use `.get()`.

Comment: The reason @heather splits the line is because the grid(...) at the end of the Label command actually returns None, whereas the Label(...) command returns the label object -- which is what you want.

Comment: @RonNorris, already edited to add that in (before your comment); apologies for not putting that in right off the bat.

Comment: @heather Thank you!! Easy fix

Comment: @RonNorris Thanks !